# In ordinal classification, how can adjacent accuracy be expressed mathematically?

Tags: classification, ordinal-data, accuracy, notation

Say that we have an ordinal classification problem where we have an ordered set of classes $\mathbb{C} = \{ C_0, C_1, \ldots, C_{K-1} \}$. We have $N$ samples, where the true and predicted classes of sample $i$ is $y_i \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\hat{y}_i \in \mathbb{C}$, respectively.

The accuracy score is the fraction of samples that are classified correctly, which [can be expressed mathematically as](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#accuracy-score)

$$\mathrm{PA}(y,\hat{y}) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} 1(\hat{y}_i=y_i) .$$

In ordinal classification, this is sometimes called *precise accuracy* or *exact accuracy*, in contrast to *adjacent accuracy*. The latter, which is used for example in [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.384.1123&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and [this](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED585773.pdf) publication, is the fraction of samples where the predicted class $\hat{y}_i$ is *off by no more than one class* from the correct class $y_i$.

Now, it is easy enough to explain with words what the adjacent accuracy is, but words are all I have ever seen in the literature. No papers I have seen express it mathematically, and I cannot think of a way to express it in a similarly simple way as the precise accuracy above. Is there a good way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about this more, the best notation for adjacent accuracy that I have come up with is

$$\mathrm{AA}(y,\hat{y}) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} 1(\hat{y}_i \approx y_i) ,$$

followed by a statement that $\hat{y}_i \approx y_i$ holds true if the predicted class $\hat{y}_i$ is off by no more than one class from the true class $y_i$. The approximation symbol $\approx$ provides the correct intuition when looking at the equation, and the statement makes the definition more precise.

I'd still be interested to know if a better notation is possible, though.

Comment: I ended up using this notation [in a journal article](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.petrol.2020.107539), so it was at least good enough to pass review in an application-oriented journal that is not too strict on mathematical formalism.